# How can I change this to use my Television Class?

Tags: java, class, boolean

> Create a Television store that can hold three Television objects in an
>   array. Use the Television class below:
>
> ```
>    class Television
>    {
>        boolean isOn;
>    } // end class Television
> ```
>
> Use a for loop to print the isOn instance variable for each Television in the
>   TelevisionStore. Use a second for loop to change the isOn instance variable for
>   each Television to “true”. Finally, use a third for loop to print the isOn instance
>   variable for each Television in the TelevisionStore array.

So I created a program that has the correct output:

```
public class TelevisionDriver
    {
    public static void main( String[] args )
        {
         boolean isOn[] = new boolean[3];
         isOn[0] = false;
         isOn[1] = false;
         isOn[2] = false;

         System.out.println( "Opening the tv store for the day... tv status:" + 
         "\n" );

         for( int x = 0; x < 3; x++ )
            {
            System.out.println( "Television" + x + " on? " + isOn[x] );
            }

         System.out.println( "\n" + "Turning the tv's on..." + "\n" );

          for( int y = 0; y < 3; y++ )
            {
            isOn[0] = true;
            isOn[1] = true;
            isOn[2] = true;

            System.out.println( "Television" + y + " on? " + isOn[y] );
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this considered right? I realized the program does not access the Television class, and am not sure how to change this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct the Television objects:

```
Television tvs[] = new Television[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    tvs[i] = new Television();
    tvs[i].isOn = false;
}
```

Then accessing whether they are on or not becomes like so:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    System.out.println("Television" + x + " on? " + tvs[x].isOn);
}
```

Really the `isOn` variable should be encapsulated and the `Television` class should have a constructor, but I'm not sure if you've learned that yet.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to create instances of your Television class.

```
Television television = new Television();
```

Then, to access its variable you could use

```
System.out.println(television.isOn);
```

However, you probably want to make that variable private and create getters and setters for it.

```
public boolean getIsOn() { return isOn; }
public boolean setIsOn(boolean on) {isOn = on;}
```

Then you can create an array of Television objects and manipulate them that way.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to create an array of **Television** objects. and then print/set their **IsOn** status. here's an (basic) example to create one object of Television and set it's status to on.

```
Television tv1 = new Television();
tv1.isOn = true;
```

now think of creating an array, which will hold the 3 objects of Television. and you can do what is asked. Good luck.